# Using Parse::RecDescent

Tags: perl, grammar, parser-generator

I have the following input

```
@Book{press,
  author    = "Press, W. and Teutolsky, S. and Vetterling, W. and Flannery B.",
  title     = "Numerical {R}ecipes in {C}: The {A}rt of {S}cientific {C}omputing",
  year      = 2007,
  publisher = "Cambridge University Press"
}
```

and I have to write a grammar for RecDescent parser generator.
Data at output should be modified for the xml structure and should look like this:

```
<book>
    <keyword>press</keyword>
    <author>Press, W.+Teutolsky, S.+Vetterling, W.+Flannery B.</author>
    <title>Numerical {R}ecipes in {C}: The {A}rt of {S}cientific {C}omputing</title>

    <year>2007</year>
    <publisher>Cambridge University Press</publisher>
</book>
```

Additional and repeated fields should be reported as errors (proper message with line number and no further parsing). I tried to start with something like this:

```
use Parse::RecDescent;

open(my $in,  "<",  "parsing.txt")  or die "Can't open parsing.txt: $!";

my $text;
while (<$in>) {
    $text .= $_;
}

print $text;

my $grammar = q {
    beginning: "\@Book\{" keyword fields "\}"           { print "<book>\n",$item[2],$item[3],"</book>"; }
    keyword: /[a-zA-Z]+/ ","                            { return "    <keyword>".$item[1]."</keyword>\n"; }
    fields: one "," two "," tree "," four               { return $item[1].$item[3].$item[5].$item[7]; }
    one: "author" "=" "\"" /[a-zA-Z\s\.\,\{\}\:]+/ "\"" {   $item[4] =~ s/\sand\s/\+/g;
                                                            return "    <author>",$item[4],"</author>\n"; }
    two: "title" "=" "\"" /[a-zA-Z\s\.\,\{\}\:]+/ "\""  {   $item[4] =~ s/\sand\s/\+/g;
                                                            return "    <title>",$item[4],"</title>\n"; }
    three: "year" "=" /[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/            {   return "    <year>",$item[3],"</year>\n"; }
    four: "publisher" "=" "\"" /[a-zA-Z\s\.\,\{\}\:]+/ "\"" 
                                                        {   $item[4] =~ s/\sand\s/\+/g;
                                                            return "    <publisher>",$item[4],"</publisher>\n"; }
};

my $parser = new Parse::RecDescent($grammar) or die ("Bad grammar!");
defined $parser->beginning($text) or die ("Bad text!");
```

But I don't even know if it's the correct way to do it. Please help.

**There's a one more tiny problem**. Tags at input might not be in that particular order, but each tag can appear only once. Do I have to write subrules for all permutations of (author,title,year,publisher)? Because I came up with:

```
fields: field "," field "," field "," field
field: one | two | three | four
```

but it obviously doesn't prevent from repeating tags.

Comment: Looks like you're off to a good start.  What problem are you having?

Comment: There is a limit to how much work you should ask your grammar to do. don't try to enforce nonrepetition in your grammar; that's something you can deal with once you've parsed it into a suitable data structure. So instead of going straight from BibTeX to XML, parse to an intermediate structure, do calculations on the structure, then output to XML afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you have a typo: `tree` instead of `three`.

I ran your program but added the lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings; # you should always have strict and warnings on
$::RD_HINT = 1; # Parse::RecDescent hints
$::RD_TRACE = 1; # Parse::RecDescent trace
```

and got this debug output:

```
 1|beginning |>>Matched terminal<< (return value:   |
  |          |[@Book{])                             |
 1|beginning |                                      |"press,\n author = "Press,
  |          |                                      |W. and Teutolsky, S. and
  |          |                                      |Vetterling, W. and Flannery
  |          |                                      |B.",\n title = "Numerical
  |          |                                      |{R}ecipes in {C}: The {A}rt
  |          |                                      |of {S}cientific
  |          |                                      |{C}omputing",\n year =
  |          |                                      |2007,\n publisher =
  |          |                                      |"Cambridge University
  |          |                                      |Press"\n}\n"
 1|beginning |Trying subrule: [keyword]             |
 2| keyword  |Trying rule: [keyword]                |
 2| keyword  |Trying production: [/[a-zA-Z]+/ ',']  |
 2| keyword  |Trying terminal: [/[a-zA-Z]+/]        |
 2| keyword  |>>Matched terminal<< (return value:   |
  |          |[press])                              |
 2| keyword  |                                      |",\n author = "Press, W. and
  |          |                                      |Teutolsky, S. and
  |          |                                      |Vetterling, W. and Flannery
  |          |                                      |B.",\n title = "Numerical
  |          |                                      |{R}ecipes in {C}: The {A}rt
  |          |                                      |of {S}cientific
  |          |                                      |{C}omputing",\n year =
  |          |                                      |2007,\n publisher =
  |          |                                      |"Cambridge University
  |          |                                      |Press"\n}\n"
 2| keyword  |Trying terminal: [',']                |
 2| keyword  |>>Matched terminal<< (return value:   |
  |          |[,])                                  |
 2| keyword  |                                      |"\n author = "Press, W. and
  |          |                                      |Teutolsky, S. and
  |          |                                      |Vetterling, W. and Flannery
  |          |                                      |B.",\n title = "Numerical
  |          |                                      |{R}ecipes in {C}: The {A}rt
  |          |                                      |of {S}cientific
  |          |                                      |{C}omputing",\n year =
  |          |                                      |2007,\n publisher =
  |          |                                      |"Cambridge University
  |          |                                      |Press"\n}\n"
 2| keyword  |Trying action                         |
 1|beginning |>>Matched subrule: [keyword]<< (return|
  |          |value: [    <keyword>press</keyword> ]|
 1|beginning |                                      |"press,\n author = "Press,
  |          |                                      |W. and Teutolsky, S. and
  |          |                                      |Vetterling, W. and Flannery
  |          |                                      |B.",\n title = "Numerical
  |          |                                      |{R}ecipes in {C}: The {A}rt
  |          |                                      |of {S}cientific
  |          |                                      |{C}omputing",\n year =
  |          |                                      |2007,\n publisher =
  |          |                                      |"Cambridge University
  |          |                                      |Press"\n}\n"
 1|beginning |Trying subrule: [fields]              |
 2|  fields  |Trying rule: [fields]                 |
 2|  fields  |Trying production: [one ',' two ','   |
  |          |three ',' four]                       |
 2|  fields  |Trying subrule: [one]                 |
 3|   one    |Trying rule: [one]                    |
 3|   one    |Trying production: ['author' '=' '\"' |
  |          |/[a-zA-Z\s\.\,{}\:]+/ '\"']           |
 3|   one    |Trying terminal: ['author']           |
 3|   one    |<<Didn't match terminal>>             |
 3|   one    |<<Didn't match rule>>                 |
 2|  fields  |<<Didn't match subrule: [one]>>       |
 2|  fields  |<<Didn't match rule>>                 |
 1|beginning |<<Didn't match subrule: [fields]>>    |
 1|beginning |<<Didn't match rule>>                 |
Bad text! at parser.pl line 32, <$in> line 6.
```

This shows that it's getting stuck at subrule `one`, and that `press,` is getting put back onto the input stream. This is because you're using `return` rather than `$return =` as the Parse::RecDescent manual [says you should](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Parse-RecDescent-1.965001/lib/Parse/RecDescent.pm#2._Using_a_return_in_an_action).

Furthermore, once you are assigning to the `$return` variable, you can no longer return a list, and must concatenate the strings together manually.

Here's the final result:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parse::RecDescent;

open(my $in,  "<",  "parsing.txt")  or die "Can't open parsing.txt: $!";

my $text;
while (<$in>) {
    $text .= $_;
}

print $text;

my $grammar = q {
    beginning: "\@Book\{" keyword fields /\s*\}\s*/           { print "<book>\n",$item[2],$item[3],"</book>"; }
    keyword: /[a-zA-Z]+/ ","                            { $return = "    <keyword>$item[1]</keyword>\n"; }
    fields: one /,\s*/ two /,\s*/ three /,\s*/ four               { $return = $item[1].$item[3].$item[5].$item[7]; }
    one: "author" "=" "\"" /[a-zA-Z\s\.\,\{\}\:]+/ "\"" {   $item[4] =~ s/\sand\s/\+/g;
                                                            $return =  "    <author>$item[4]</author>\n"; }
    two: "title" "=" "\"" /[a-zA-Z\s\.\,\{\}\:]+/ "\""  {   $item[4] =~ s/\sand\s/\+/g;
                                                            $return =  "    <title>$item[4]</title>\n"; }
    three: "year" "=" /[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/            {   $return = "    <year>$item[3]</year>\n"; }
    four: "publisher" "=" "\"" /[a-zA-Z\s\.\,\{\}\:]+/ "\"" 
                                                        {   $item[4] =~ s/\sand\s/\+/g;
                                                            $return = "    <publisher>$item[4]</publisher>\n"; }
};

my $parser = new Parse::RecDescent($grammar) or die ("Bad grammar!");
defined $parser->beginning($text) or die ("Bad text!");
```

Comment: The '$return = ' instead of 'return' helped a lot.